# Flutter ambiguous import on a class that does not exist in the framework

Tags: flutter, dart

All of a sudden I'm receiving ambiguous import errors on classes that absolutely don't exist in the locations stated in the error message.  As an example the name of the class is something like `BusinessEntityResponse` (ie GetUserNameResponse) and Flutter/dart is reporting it as ambiguous in the framework.   Any ideas on how to address this (tried flutter clean) or why it is occurring or how to troubleshoot it?

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/projects/git/curbside/my_app/lib/data/settings/settings.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": {
        "value": "ambiguous_import",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#ambiguous_import",
            "path": "/tools/diagnostic-messages",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev",
            "fragment": "ambiguous_import"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The name 'MyAppClassResponse' is defined in the libraries 'package:my_app/api/dto.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'.\nTry using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 81,
    "startColumn": 10,
    "endLineNumber": 81,
    "endColumn": 36,
    "tags": []
}
```

This seems to be indicative of a larger problem as the following lines are also throwing compilation errors all of a sudden:

class AppEntryWeb extends StatelessWidget  --> Classes can only extend other classes.

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/projects/git/curbside/my_app/lib/ui/launch-web.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": {
        "value": "extends_non_class",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#extends_non_class",
            "path": "/tools/diagnostic-messages",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev",
            "fragment": "extends_non_class"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Classes can only extend other classes.\nTry specifying a different superclass, or removing the extends clause.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 12,
    "startColumn": 27,
    "endLineNumber": 12,
    "endColumn": 42,
    "tags": []
}
```

Comment: can you please provide minimal reproduction code?
Thanks.

Comment: The classes mentioned are all basic data classes with primitive properties.  They aren't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth, the errors seemed to have occurred when the visual studio code flutter extension updated to 3.15.0.  I uninstalled the flutter/dart extensions, shut down vs code, reopened and reinstalled them which seemed to have fixed the issue.

Further information, the visual studio code analyzer problem window was reporting different information from running flutter analyze.  Not sure why.